# How to show data from database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

i am new in terms of php or in programming i know only few in php. I have a question and it probably simple for you guys, i am having a problem here to show data from mysql database, i have this code:

```
<?php
    $getfriend= mysql_query("SELECT * from members");
    $friend=mysql_fetch_array($getfriend);
    $rowfriend=mysql_num_rows($getfriend);

    //$users = array()--->i think i have to put it into a array, but i don't know how
    if($rowfriend>1){
        for ($x=0; $x < 10; $x++){
        echo '<tr><td name =""><img src="" alt="" width="50" height="50" /> </td></tr>';
        }                 
    }

?>
```

what i want is to show pictures, names, gender, bday and so on... which is all from mysql database. i used here the so called for loop just to control how many rows i am going to show in page. my code is working it shows 3  with  the problem here is i don't know how to put its content to the td's. can guys help me doing this?

Comment: [Use](http://php.net/mysqli) [the](http://php.net/pdo) [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php). Get used to reading.

Comment: To add onto the previous comment. `mysql` is unsecured. Use `mysqli` or even better `PDO`. You could ignore the warning, but in the long run It'll cost you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you try something like this:-

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password for your db
mysql_select_db('your_db_name');

$query = "SELECT * from members";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['age'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close();
```

Here i am using a  while loop to iterate over the rows fetched and i find this the easiest way to do so.

I would also recommend switching over to mysqli and PDO (if you're determined to learn new concepts) since mysql has been depreciated.

> EDIT: Asked how to limit records in db

Just change the way you write your Select queries to something like this:-

```
Query SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,5 //will return 5 records starting from the first record.

Query SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5 //will also give the same result as above query.
```

If in that table there are fewer than 5 records then it will not fail but return whatever records are there.

```
Query SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 6,5 //will return record 7,8,9,10,11 as the index starts from 0.
```

Does this give you a fair idea?

Comment: the above code is connected already to mysql, and it shows 3 td's because i have 3 rows in my database. will this code of yours show all the data from database?

Comment: sorry i think i have to try it

Comment: It will show all the data, you have to add the fields you want to show by using $row['field_name'] above

Comment: thanks, sorry i cant vote you up, for i am new in this site ... more powers.. :)

Comment: Do you see a transparent tick mark next to my answer, please select that to indicate this is the correct answer and the tick mark will turn green. Since you asked the question you will still have that privilege. Thank you :)

Comment: your answer is best. can you teach me on how to save value in a sesion so that when i click name in td i will be redirected to another page that is containing the information base on the name i clicked.

Comment: the other thing @Damien hawks is, how can i control it? let say i wan to show only 3 rows from my database?

Comment: Please google "session variable php" for that and sure if you wanted to limit the records fetched, you can use the edit i've made in my answer.